# Using awk in solaris

Tags: awk, solaris

I am working on Solaris 5.10 and I would like to parse `/etc/default/passwd` and check the minimum password length. Following is the script I'm using:

```
if awk -v x=1 '$1 == "PASSLENGTH" && $2 == "6" {x=0} END{exit x}' /etc/default/passwd
        then 
            echo "Control Area: User Identity Management; Ensure that minimum password length is set ; compliant" >> /etc/chef/report.txt        
        else
            echo "Control Area: User Identity Management; Ensure that minimum password length is set ; Non compliant" >> /etc/chef/report.txt        
        fi
```

If the minimum `PASSLENGTH` is equal to `6`, I echo as compliant in my `report.txt` file. But the problem is my code is not going inside the if block, even if the value of the `PASSLENGTH` variable is equal to `6` in `/etc/default/passwd`.

Comment: Why awk? You'd get a lot more help here if you wrote this in, say, python.

Comment: Run the awk command on its own and see what the output is, it is likely both arguments are not matching.

Comment: Solaris != linux. you should remove the linux tag.

Comment: @Jidder running awk on it's own gives a syntax error,
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @gfc It does that if you just run the command exactly the same on command line ?

Comment: Try using `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of the standard awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PASSLENGTH` is written in the format `PASSLENGTH=N`.
Awk uses space/tab/newline as the default separator.
That means that your `$1` is actually `PASSLENGTH=6` and `$2` is set to nothing explaining why the if statement is failing.

Try

```
if awk -F= -v x=1 '$1 == "PASSLENGTH" && $2 == "6" {x=0} END{exit x}' /etc/default/passwd
        then 
            echo "Control Area: User Identity Management; Ensure that minimum password     length is set ; compliant" >> /etc/chef/report.txt        
        else
            echo "Control Area: User Identity Management; Ensure that minimum password length is set ; Non compliant" >> /etc/chef/report.txt        
fi
```

Also you could change the awk so you dont have to declare a variable at the start

```
awk -F= '$1 == "PASSLENGTH" && $2 != "6" {x=1} END{exit x}
```

All in awk, shortest i think it can be

```
  awk  '/^PASSLENGTH=6/{x=1}
  END {print "Control Area: User Identity Management; Ensure that minimum password length is set; " (x?"compliant":"non compliant") >> "/etc/chef/report.txt"}' /etc/default/passwd
```

Comment: Note that it can happen that the configuration file contains a `#` in the beginning of the line. A more robust solution could be `/^PASSLENGTH=6/`.